# SQL inline view subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inline-view

Is it possible to reference an inline view defined in the "FROM" clause from a subquery in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT tmp.TeacherName,
       tmp.courseid,
       tmp.AvgAttendingStudents
FROM   (SELECT T.TeacherID              AS ID,
               T.TeacherName            AS Name,
               C.CourseID               AS CourseID,
               avg(L.AttendingStudents) AS AvgAttendingStudents
        FROM   Teachers AS T
               join Courses AS C
                 ON C.TeacherID = T.TeacherID
               join Lessons AS L
                 ON L.CourseID = C.CourseID
        GROUP  BY T.TeacherID,
                  C.CourseID) AS tmp
WHERE  tmp.AvgAttendingStudents = (SELECT max(AvgAttendingStudents)
                                   FROM   tmp AS tmp2
                                   WHERE  tmp2.TeacherID = tmp.TeacherID);
```

In this example i'm trying to list all the teachers and for each of them I want to show the course having the maximum average of attending students (calculated on all lessons). I tried to use an inline view (tmp) to calculate the average number of attending students for each course, but I don't know if I can reference that view in the subquery SELECT max(...).
I need this to work with Oracle, but unfortunately at the moment I don't have any Oracle database to try it. I tried with MySQL (since I don't think I'm using any Oracle-specific features), but as expected I get the error "Table 'db.tmp' doesn't exist".
Is this somehow possible with Oracle?

Here's my example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
  (
     CourseID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     CourseName VARCHAR(32),
     TeacherID  INTEGER
  );

CREATE TABLE Teachers
  (
     TeacherID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     TeacherName VARCHAR(32)
  );

CREATE TABLE Lessons
  (
     LessonDate        TIMESTAMP,
     CourseID          INTEGER,
     AttendingStudents INTEGER,
     PRIMARY KEY (LessonDate, CourseID)
  );
```

(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that you can't reference the derived table ("inline view") that way. You need to rewrite the derived table ("inline view") to a common table expression:

You also have other errors in there. In the derived table you rename `TeacherID` to `ID` and `TeacherName` to `Name` so you need to use those column names not the "real" ones.

Also Oracle doesn't support `AS` for a table alias, so you need to get rid of those as well.

So a direct rewrite of the statement would be:

```
with tmp as (
  SELECT T.TeacherID              AS ID,
         T.TeacherName            AS Name,
         C.CourseID               AS CourseID,
         avg(L.AttendingStudents) AS AvgAttendingStudents
  FROM   Teachers T
         join Courses C
           ON C.TeacherID = T.TeacherID
         join Lessons L
           ON L.CourseID = C.CourseID
  GROUP  BY T.TeacherID,
            C.CourseID
)
SELECT tmp.name,
       tmp.courseid,
       tmp.AvgAttendingStudents
FROM tmp
where tmp.AvgAttendingStudents = (SELECT max(AvgAttendingStudents)
                                  FROM   tmp tmp2
                                  WHERE  tmp2.id = tmp.id);
```

However the above will **not** work in Oracle because of the invalid use of the `group by` and aggregate function. The above will result in "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression", see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32a514/5)

For this to work you need to use a window function in the CTE and get rid of the `group by`:

```
with tmp as (
  SELECT T.TeacherID              AS ID,
         T.TeacherName            AS Name,
         C.CourseID               AS CourseID,
         avg(L.AttendingStudents) over (partition by t.teacherid, c.courseid) AS avgattendingstudents 
  FROM   Teachers T
         join Courses C
           ON C.TeacherID = T.TeacherID
         join Lessons L
           ON L.CourseID = C.CourseID
)
SELECT tmp.name,
       tmp.courseid,
       tmp.AvgAttendingStudents
FROM tmp
where tmp.AvgAttendingStudents = (SELECT max(AvgAttendingStudents)
                                  FROM   tmp tmp2
                                  WHERE  tmp2.id = tmp.id);
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32a514/7) for an example.

---

Note that you can not test the above queries with MySQL because it does not support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) like common table expressions or window functions.

But you can use the SQLFiddle examples to test it with data.

Answer (score 0):

You may use having clause, which can provide you a way to constraint an agregate function.

Here an example :

```
    SELECT T.TeacherID              AS ID,
           T.TeacherName            AS Name,
           C.CourseID               AS CourseID,
           avg(L.AttendingStudents) AS AvgAttendingStudents
    FROM   Teachers AS T
           join Courses AS C
             ON C.TeacherID = T.TeacherID
           join Lessons AS L
             ON L.CourseID = C.CourseID
    GROUP  BY T.TeacherID,
              T.TeacherName
              C.CoursesID
    HAVING  avg(L.AttendingStudents) = (SELECT max(AvgAttendingStudents)
                               FROM   Teachers AS tmp2
                               WHERE  tmp2.TeacherID = T.TeacherID);
```

I just remove your first nested query and change AvgAttendingStudents to avg(L.AttendingStudents) (beacause you can't work with variable onto Having clause) and add selected attributs in Group clause, I don't test but here the way to do the trick.

Don't forget to add your not agregated var selected in group clause.

Here a documentation on [having clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

Comment: There is no column `AvgAttendingStudents` in the `teachers` table. And Oracle does not support `AS` for a table alias.